# How can I handle 'Session Trampling' error while authenticating multiple sessions in the same browser with node-oidc-provider?

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, session-state, cookie-session, node-oidc-provider

When we try to open multiple browser instances and try to login with same user credentials, we get different kinds of errors. The very first browser session is loaded fine but the further sessions throw error. "Something went wrong".

When trying to authenticate 2 sessions in the same browser. Both are throwing an error.

OidcConfiguration holds the name of interaction or other cookies that are required during oidc provider interactions.

OidcConfiguration is injected into OidcProvider at the time of boot-up. Configuration object is formed at the time of OidcProvider constructor, and it is private to OidcProvier.

During cookieName call, OidcProvider refers to the private copy of Configuration to fetch the cookie name. So, we cannot change the cookie name per request/tab or per client and cookie name is fixed.

Error message: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/14uOr.png)